# drawing points on face based on landmarks

Tags: java, android, face-detection, google-vision

I am trying to draw points on face based on land marks i am using google vision api to detect face and landmarks, **My question is how i calculate the value of `scale` variable**

```
 for (Landmark landmark : face.getLandmarks()) {
        int cx = (int) (landmark.getPosition().x * scale);
        int cy = (int) (landmark.getPosition().y * scale);
        canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, 10, paint);
    }
```

I find this solution on [this](http://forum.yourwebapp.mobi/an-introduction-to-face-detection-on-android/) website but this solution not work for me because i trying to use live camera preview (e.g. real time) not try to detect from image

```
 double scale = Math.min( viewWidth / imageWidth, viewHeight / imageHeight );
```